# haproxy replace header value

Tags: regex, replace, haproxy, replacewith

can you please suggest haproxy heade value replace config to match for a string & replace the value

Here is sample header

```
X-Application-Context →MyService:arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4:number
```

here is what i have tried

```
http-response replace-value X-Application-Context ^(.*?(\barg1\b)[^$]*)$ \1banana\2
```

Here is what i am getting now..

```
X-Application-Context →MyService:arg1bananaarg1,arg2,arg3,arg4:number
```

if you notice 'arg1' is coming as a duplicate..here is what i want..

```
 X-Application-Context →MyService:banana,arg2,arg3,arg4:number
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what has worked for me ..

```
    http-response replace-value X-Application-Context (.*)(\barg1\b)(.*)$ \1banana\3
```